# Where can I find documentation for IDA Freeware?

Tags: ida, documentation

I have looked at [the official documentation page](https://hex-rays.com/documentation/) and it doesn't have an entry for IDA Freeware. Is it available at all? Is there a popular unofficial one? Do I just read the one for IDA Pro?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. You basically read the IDA Pro one and there are restrictions (target CPUs, loaders etc ...) which make it deviate from IDA Pro.

Comment: If you are not sure - How about pressing F1 while using IDA freeware? It has some doc though I don't know how much of it is relevant to you.